# Specify the number of grids in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

`GridLayout` creates a grid matrix whose dimension (no of rows and columns) is customizable using two int parameters that is takes as part of its constructor.

Why don't we have such a similar option in `GridBagLayout`?

In a typical scenario using a `Gridbaglayout`, If i wanted a component to be placed at say extreme right or middle or at any other arbitrary location wouldn't it help if I know the size of Grid Matrix?.

Answer (score 7):

Each 'row' of a `GridBagLayout` can have different numbers of columns, so it hardly makes sense to specify it in the constructor.

Comment: are you referring to the feature where a component can occupy more than one grid cell using gridwidth and gridheight property?

Comment: Basically, yes.  And note that advice also applies to columns spanning multiple rows as well.

Comment: but that features just talks about how components span across multiple grid cells, while the underlying Grid remains to be a perfect Matrix of cells right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on that, sorry.  But either way.  The idea of GBL is to account for grids that are not as simple as `GridLayout` handles, and I guess the programmers that wrote it felt that if you were using GBL, you might as well just get used to working with the `GridBagConstraints`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you specify the grid coordinates of a component through `GridBagContraints` when adding the component. The `GridBagLayout`’s size is then determined automatically by the largest coordinates (and probably the grid width and grid height of the component at these coordinates).

Comment: I have updated my question. I am not sure if I can place a component at any arbitrary location of the grid if I dont know the dimensions of the grid matrix. If it is at the boundaries of the Grid then it is easier, but otherwise it doesn't seem to be straight forward.

Comment: That is really a separate question that should be asked on a ..separate question.  You'll get a better response by asking a more specific GBL based question anyway.  For best help be sure to include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & ASCII art (or a line drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.